# How to install Gensim on Windows 7

Tags: python, gensim

I have Windows 7 and WinPython 3.4.3.2; trying to install Gensim from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gensim

I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerCmd>pip install e:\Python\gensim-0.12.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Processing e:\python\gensim-0.12.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.2.0 in m:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages (from gensim==0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.3 in m:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages (from gensim==0.12.1)
Collecting smart-open>=1.2.1 (from gensim==0.12.1)
  Using cached smart_open-1.2.1.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Joomler\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-49b17fh6\smart-open\setup.py", line 28, in <module>
    long_description = read('README.rst'),
  File "C:\Users\Joomler\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-49b17fh6\smart-open\setup.py", line 21, in read
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
  File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 4345: character maps to <undefined>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Joomler\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-49b17fh6\smart-open\setup.py", line 28, in <module>
        long_description = read('README.rst'),
      File "C:\Users\Joomler\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-49b17fh6\smart-open\setup.py", line 21, in read
        return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
      File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 4345: character maps to <undefined>
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

      File "C:\Users\Joomler\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-49b17fh6\smart-open\setup.py", line 28, in <module>

        long_description = read('README.rst'),

      File "C:\Users\Joomler\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-49b17fh6\smart-open\setup.py", line 21, in read

        return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()

      File "M:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode

        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 4345: character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Joomler\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-49b17fh6\smart-open
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smart_open manually from setup.py.

There was a problem file `README.rst` - I erased all data in it, to ensure that no bad characters would be printed.

Now I need to manually install Gensim, because it downloads `smart_open` automatically. Unfortunately, I am not able to `import gensim`. I'm having the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'gensim'
```

But if I execute `pip install -U gensim` I'm able to see that all requirements are already satisfied:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: gensim in m:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.12.1-py3.4-win-amd64.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.3 in m:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages (from gensim)
Requirement already up-to-date: scipy>=0.7.0 in m:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages (from gensim)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5.0 in m:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages (from gensim)
Requirement already up-to-date: smart-open>=1.2.1 in m:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\smart_open-1.2.1-py3.4.egg (from gensim)
Requirement already up-to-date: boto>=2.32 in m:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\boto-2.38.0-py3.4.egg (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
Requirement already up-to-date: httpretty==0.8.6 in m:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\httpretty-0.8.6-py3.4.egg (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
Requirement already up-to-date: bz2file in m:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\bz2file-0.98-py3.4.egg (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
```

Any hints?

Edit 15/08/2015: Install was successful. I just had to clean up older attemps and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe, the error message suggests, a Python3 'on windows' compatibility bug.

Comment: I quess it is a common UnicodeDecodeError error, but how to fix

Comment: solved by the author of the gensim ( now,  wait for next release) : https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/428